# Grid that reorganizes its cells depending on window size?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid-layout

My application loads a series of 64x64 pixel images and displays them on a 4x4 grid. If I change the application window's size, I'd like the grid to reconfigure itself. Say if I resize the application's window so that its client area happens to be 128 x 512 then the grid would reconfigure itself to become 2x8.

Is there a control that can do this?
Thanks!

Comment: you can bind the window's width and height to the definitions of 
Grid.Column , Grid.ColumnSpan , and rows with a converter of your logic , i'll try to build a little app for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`WrapPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) instead of a `Grid`.

Comment: could you show a little example how he would control the positioning of the child elements with a wrap panel .?

Comment: @eranotzap OP did not ask for control of positioning the images in specific grid cells. If the child elements all have fixed size (as 64 x 64 pixel images do) a WrapPanel is the perfect container. In case the child sizes can be different (and you want to force them to be equal), i'd suggest to use a UniformGrid and bind its `Columns` property to its `ActualWidth` property with a suitable converter.